# Selection using dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a problem with my query using dapper, whether someone imagine to help me and say where I'm doing the wrong, is currently showing me an error at the date when I put a breik point, how to correct it properly? thank you all for help

this is my current code

```
public string GetBezeichnung(int LP, DateTime date)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = _ConnectionString;
        var output = connection.Query<string>("SELECT ZER_Bezeichnung FROM Z_ERFASSUNG WHERE ZER_LPE = " + LP + " AND ZER_Datum = " + date).FirstOrDefault();
        return output;
    }
}
```

and this is the result with which I get an error

[image: image description here]

Comment: 100% parameterise the query. If you run with the solution that @Shaun provided as a general pattern you will open yourself up to Sql Injection attacks when dealing with user input. Using parameterised arguments bypasses the issue of Sql Injection altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try parameterizing the query.

```
public string GetBezeichnung(int LP, DateTime date)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = @"
SELECT ZER_Bezeichnung 
FROM Z_ERFASSUNG 
WHERE ZER_LPE = @LP
  AND ZER_Datum = @date"
        var output = connection.Query<string>(sql, new { LP = LP, date = date }).FirstOrDefault();
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Parrish Husband, but the Second Paramater has to be "Date = date".

In your example there are no ' around the date so AQL thinks its a bunch or things.

Changing it to

```
var output = connection.Query<string>("SELECT ZER_Bezeichnung FROM Z_ERFASSUNG WHERE ZER_LPE = " + LP + " AND ZER_Datum = '" + date + "'").FirstOrDefault();
```

will make it work.

Comment: Note this would still be open to SQL injection.

Comment: @ParrishHusband I prefer your answer over this one, but I don't think you're right about Sql injection.  This code is within a method that takes an int and a DateTime as parameters.  You can't use either of those for Sql injection, AFAIK.  Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @Archer interesting point, and I think you're right in this case.  Although it's never a bad idea to get in the habit of being safe, and there's no telling when a new exploit will appear.

Comment: @ParrishHusband I completely agree with you about forging good habits.  It's the reason I prefer your answer as I'd parameterize the query (if not make it an SP - depends on where I'm working).

Comment: @Archer, its about the establishment of the pattern. If it works for dates, chances are it will get copied for strings and over time eventually user input will flow via this path of least resistance too.

Comment: @Quibblesome I agree with that, as you can tell from my previous comment.  I was merely pointing out that *this example* is not vulnerable to Sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line of code so that it will match the exact date. if the time for the date is different then it will not fetch that records.

```
var output = connection.Query<string>("SELECT ZER_Bezeichnung FROM Z_ERFASSUNG WHERE ZER_LPE = " + LP + " AND Cast( ZER_Datum as DATE) = Cast('" + date + "' as DATE)").FirstOrDefault();
```